# Errors occurred while compiling flink-table-planner_2.12 of the released version 1.15.0

Tags: apache-flink

some of the errors are:

```
error: not found: type SqlExprToRexConverterFactory
[INFO]   def getSqlExprToRexConverterFactory: SqlExprToRexConverterFactory
error: not found: type SqlExprToRexConverterFactory
[INFO]     toRexFactory: SqlExprToRexConverterFactory)
error: not found: type SqlExprToRexConverterFactory
[INFO]   override def getSqlExprToRexConverterFactory: SqlExprToRexConverterFactory = toRexFactory
```

It's all the scala codes which import the Java codes. They have a loop import. I did not change anything.

What should I do to solve these same problems to ensure a successful compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Flink 1.15 release notes https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/release-notes/flink-1.15/ you see that there have been multiple changes to Flink's Table API dependencies.

If you want to have the previous behavior:

> Users can still swap `flink-table-planner-loader` with flink-table-planner_2.12 located in opt/. flink-table-uber has been split into flink-table-api-java-uber, flink-table-planner(-loader), and flink-table-runtime. Scala users need to explicitly add a dependency to flink-table-api-scala or flink-table-api-scala-bridge.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I failed because I use the wrong maven build plugin 'maven-scala-plugin' to compile before.